# Mistake in Mathematica administrative division data in Africa

Tags: bugs, geography, entity

I would like to, firstly, report that, I think there are a number of mistakes in the administrative level data. Or, at least, it is not clear to me why there should be differences in some definitions between countries.

If I obtain a list of administrative divisions for Angola,

> EntityValue[  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
>        "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> 
>       Entity["Country", "Angola"]}], "Entities"]

The list of results that follows from this command (see below) matches 18 Angola's official division level 1 districts (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivisions_of_Angola)).

Whereas for Burkina Faso, this is not the case, and the same command seems to return the 45 admin level 2 entities (see below), rather than the 13 admin level 1 districts (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivisions_of_Burkina_Faso)).

I have also noticed issues with other aspects of the admin data, for example, Swaziland has the incorrect number of districts by this measure, with one of them actually being in South Africa.

Does anyone know how I can get the entities I want -- a list of **true** admin level 1 districts for countries in Africa? I notice that there is an EntityClass object,

> EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "ADM1"]

But, to tell you the truth, I haven't a clue how to use this to get countries in Africa. Nor am I confident that the data which come from these attempts will be correct. If anyone does have an idea how to do this, though, please let me know. Best, Ben

Angola:

> {Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Bengo", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Benguela", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Bie", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Cabinda", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Cunene", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Huambo", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Huila", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"KuandoKubango", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"KwanzaNorte", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"KwanzaSul", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Luanda", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"LundaNorte", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"LundaSul", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Malanje", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Moxico", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Namibe", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Uige", "Angola"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Zaire", "Angola"}]}

Burkina Faso:

> EntityValue[  Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {EntityProperty[
>        "AdministrativeDivision", "ParentRegion"] -> 
>       Entity["Country", "BurkinaFaso"]}], "Entities"] {Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Bale", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Bam", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Banwa", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Bazega", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Bougouriba", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Boulgou", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Boulkiemde", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Comoe", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Ganzourgou", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Gnagna", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Gourma", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Houet", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Ioba", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Kadiogo", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Kenedougou", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Komandjari", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Kompienga", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Kossi", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Koulpelogo", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Kouritenga", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Kourweogo", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Leraba", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Loroum", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Mouhoun", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Nahouri", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Namentenga", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Nayala", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Noumbiel", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Oubritenga", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Oudalan", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Passore", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Poni", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Sanguie", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Sanmatenga", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Seno", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Sissili", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Soum", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Sourou", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Tapoa", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Tuy", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Yagha", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Yatenga", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Ziro", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Zondoma", "BurkinaFaso"}],
>   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Zoundweogo", "BurkinaFaso"}]}

Comment: Yeah, would be great if somebody would curate the "curated data". I think you should send hints to errors in curated data directly to Wolfram support.

Comment: I've contacted Wolfram about this and so will wait and see what they say.

Comment: any responses from Wolfram regarding this topic ? i have similar issues with districts of Czech Republic (the latest lowest level is not available) edit: i cannot write comments. Actually, i am looking also for some possiblity of division the subdivisions according : "AdministrativeDivision" class level ("ADM1", "ADM2", or "ADM3") but there is nothing nowhwere written on manuals though these classes I assume

Comment: @RichieČučuliačik, please report any errors you find in the curated data directly to tech support.

Comment: per @JasonB it would be good to directly notify Wolfram Tech Support.

Comment: Posting these types of issues to this forum is not helpful. Please send these reports to Wolfram Technical Support.

Comment: I've done so. They didn't write back to me. The purpose of posting this originally was to check that I wasn't making any mistakes in interpretation.